# New array of pointers to class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I want the class `OUT` to hold an array of `IN` pointers. How many is unknown. This is what I have so far.

```
class OUT{
    class IN{/**/};
    IN** IN_handle;
    int m_size_in;
    OUT(int size_in):m_size_in(size_in){
        IN_handle = new *IN[size_in];
    }
    ~OUT(){
        for(int i=0; i<m_size_in; i++){
            delete IN_handle[i];
        }
        delete IN_handle;
    }
};
```

compiler says:

> cannot convert 'int**' to 'OUT::IN**' in assignment

Comment: use a `std::vector<IN*>`

Comment: if you do so, you dont have to take care about the memory management. But you still would have to delete the `IN`s that the elements point to (at least thats what you do with the current code).

Comment: Generally speaking: Don't use arrays, dynamic memory allocation with naked pointers, and other such C structures if you don't absolutely have to. C++ is so nice with `<vector>`, `<string>`, and smart pointers that way...

Comment: `new *IN` ??  Did you mean `new IN*` ?

Comment: I agree with @DevSolar. Anyway, notice that the c-tor and d-tor are private. So you can't create an instance of this class externally.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` will save you a lot of work :

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class OUT{
    public:
        class IN{/**/};
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IN>> IN_handle;

        void add(std::unique_ptr<IN> &&new_data)
        {
            IN_handle.push_back(std::move(new_data));
        }

        OUT()
        {
        }

        ~OUT()
        {
        }

        // Functions to manipulate IN_handle
};
```

and to use it:

```
OUT out;
out.add(std::make_unique<OUT::IN>());
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/:

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in size.

Also `std::unique_ptr` take care of deleting allocated memory, so no need to be worry about that point ;)

Comment: Now, just need to add the creation of the objects (`make_unique`) and this is a top notch answer.

Comment: I would suggest to mention explicitly, that `unique_ptr` takes care of deleting. Ignorants like me might not be aware

Comment: @Garf365 well, thanks for not mentioning it in the first version of the answer. I still believe that looking something up by myself makes a better learning experience than just reading it on SO :P. Seriously, I am still not best friend of smarpointers, and imho this is a really nice example

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `std::vector` with `std::unique_ptr` as your vector elements. Do not manually manage your pointers or dynamic arrays.